# curl on a page which shares url with other pages

Tags: php, curl, box-api

I'm trying to use [curl in php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to post values for a form to the form's action url.  At the next page, after a user on a browser would have clicked "submit", I want to curl the next page to choose the "I agree, continue" button.  However, these two pages both share the same url, so no matter what I do the url always points to the first page with the form.  In other words, the action url for the form on the first page is itself.

That was the general idea, now for some specifics.  I'm trying to automate the login process on OAuth 2.0 for Box.com because my app will always log in with its own admin account, not the user's own account.  The two pages I refer to are the box.com account login page, and the allow/deny page following it.

Another thought: let's say the two pages had distinct urls.  After clicking "allow" on the second page in a browser, box would redirect back to my app using the redirect_uri I gave it.  How would I curl that, because the action url for the form on the second page is STILL itself.  If I did somehow successfully curl it, where would I get the authorization code to exchange for an access token?

Thank you for any replies.  I'm new to curl, so examples and such would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of your Box activity occurs within your admin account then you shouldn't need to log users in at all.  You can simply store the access/refresh token pair for your admin account and use this to authenticate your Box requests.  If you *are* touching another user's data, then automating button clicks during the OAuth login/authorization process is really not cool.

Comment: Oh that's a good idea.  Don't worry, I don't touch the box accounts of my app's users.  In fact, they don't even need to have a box account.

Comment: Cool, and just to recap: OAuth2 doesn't provide login functionality, but rather a security layer between your app and a Box user's data. It allows Box to ask that user directly if he/she is OK with your app touching their data.  You are out of the loop until Box redirects the user back to your app with a 'yep' or 'nope.'